# Is there a way to print in Xcode 12.4 without generating a build to preview your app in a simulation?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode12

Right now when I want to print something I generate a new build and tap on a view to print out some content, but I haven't found anything that says I can just run some hotkey to print out some data to look underneath the hood of some JSON blob or maybe just see the type.

For example in Python I can simply just run the file with `python file.py`. Is something like this possible with Xcode?

I'm currently using Xcode 12.4. Thank you!

Comment: Python is interpreted. Swift is compiled. You need to compile it to run it.  For prototyping small pieces of code a playground may be useful.  Xcode also has a powerful debugger that lets you set breakpoints, examine variables and evaluate expressions.

Comment: Ah got it, thanks for that clarification. Makes sense now!